# Magento add product to wishlist in REST Api

Tags: magento-1.9, wishlist

I am trying to add product to wishlist with below script in custom REST API  its not working, but this below script is working at controller and magento root folder

```
        $wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer('67', true);
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('214');    

        $buyRequest = new Varien_Object(array());

        $result = $wishlist->addNewItem($product, $buyRequest);
        $wishlist->save();
```

Comment: Rest API does not support the wishlist

Comment: Thanks Arunendra, but am developing custom API whether it support or not support

Comment: Are u add product to wishlist api? @Ramesh